# GEOLOCALIZACIÓN EN TIEMPO REAL

Tags: google-maps, aplicación-web

Buen día, mi pregunta es sencilla hacia personas con experiencia en maps, fíjense que eh trabajado un poco con la api de google maps en web, en la cual hice lo básico (calcule distancia entre 2 puntos, agregue markers y detecte automáticamente mi ubicación), entonces me ha surgido una duda con respecto a la geolocalización en tiempo real (en realidad no se si se llame realmente así, corrijanme si es el caso por favor), a lo que me refiero por ejemplo si yo me muevo el marker se actualice con respecto a mis movimientos, algo así como lo lo que hace uber con sus conductores (te muestra la ruta y a la vez con respeto al movimiento va cambiando en tiempo real el marker que hace referencia a tu ubicación) o en la misma app de google (cuando queremos ir a un lugar y nos dice por donde ir en tiempo real según cada que avanzamos un tramo en la ruta), ¿es posible hacer eso en programación web con la api de google maps o solo esta limitado a programación móvil?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Esto de aquí es en una app móvil, pero yo quiero hacer lo mismo con programación web, en la cual la ubicación me la proporcione el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la api `TransportTracker` de google. Aquí tienes más información:

https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo! :)